# System-wide scheduling modification

Tags: process, scheduling, real-time

Is there a way to change the process scheduling policy of the whole system? For example, I want to change the default SCHED_OTHER to SCHED_RR for all processes. The command `chrt` operates on a process. I would like to change the settings system-wide. Any idea about that?

UPDATE:

To be more specific, I want to launch some commands, e.g. `tar` with different policies and the problem is that prior to launching the program, I don't know the process ID.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. If SCHED_RR works even if all processes have it, so would SCHED_OTHER, but with more overhead. What is it that you want to achieve that way?

Comment: I want to change the policy for some programs. For example, I want to test "tar" command with different policies. However, prior to running the command, I don't know the PID. What you said make sense. So, I want to know how can I achieve that?

Comment: Ok, that means you should really edit your question to ask that! (also, different priorities won't do much for `tar`: it's IO-bound, not scheduling/CPU bound at all. You cannot speed up reading and writing data from storage by checking more often that there's no data to process yet)

Comment: Yes I know. I am testing some programs, including, zip, wget, matrix multiplication, graphic and so on. I would also like to use perf for measuring energy with different policies, not only the performance.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : If I of course fully agree with your first comment, I do not necessarily agree with your second (not much interesting for IO bound processes.) Just think of a sound server. Typically io-bound process. If underlying sound card interrupts are threaded (hence running as RT threads) running the sound server RT does make sense since it will then be able to precisely manage the appropriate synchro between the different data flows.

Comment: @mahmood : I edited my answer for a possible more handy but more dangerous way to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

chrt can not only change the scheduling priority of a running process (you'll actually need the pid) but also launch a new process following a particular scheduling policy :

> ```
>    chrt [options] priority command argument ...
>
>    chrt [options] -p [priority] PID
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    chrt sets or retrieves the real-time scheduling attributes of an
>    existing PID, or runs command with the given attributes.
> ```

So if you want to launch tar running SCHED_RR rtprio 10 straight from the beginning, simply

```
chrt -r 10 tar blahblahraroptions
```

If, as written in comments, it would make no sense to have all running processes running the same scheduling policy at the same priority level, there is just no way to achieve that.
It is however possible to launch all your users' processes automatically to your desired scheduling policy / priority since this is (per default) inherited by child processes.

1/ fork a bash process scheduled SCHED_FIFO / priority 10 :

```
$ chrt -f 10 bash
```

2/ Whatever process launched from now on will be scheduled identically without the need to use chrt.

```
/proc/2074 $ ps -eHo pid,ppid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,comm
...
4168  2074  4168 FF      10   -  50         bash
4192  4168  4192 FF      10   -  50           ps
...
```

**Use with caution and only for your test purposes, and of course do avoid launching fork bombs as well as assigning the highest possible priority !**

Comment: Did you verify your method? Because while `tar zcf x.tar.gz file.c` works, the command `chrt -r 10 tar zcf x.tar.gz file.c` returns `chrt: failed to set pid 0's policy: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: @mahmood : errr ? Of course I test first what I advise to do. I had launched chrt -f 10 tar cvf BenchMarks.tar BenchMarks succesfully. At least could we both agree that… I verified my method more often than you… appear reading the fucking manuals ;-)